# How can I fix a sigabrt error on my macOS Hight Sierra?

Tags: python, qt

`[qt.qpa.plugin] Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstall application may fix this problem.`

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Please help me fix this. I am doing a school project so helping me would be very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are missing a plugin and you will have to install it on your mac.

`pip3 install opencv-python-headless` from your terminal should do the job assuming you are on python3

Comment: Thanks! Im actually using python 3 so this will be helpful. I will let you know if anything works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I did try this but this happened:

Comment: pip3 install opencv-python-headless
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python-headless in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.2.0.32)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opencv-python-headless) (1.18.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: But Im using python 2.7. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Looks like you are on python3.8. whats exactly are you trying to do to get that error?